# Objective-C Base class for view and text field

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield, radix

So I'm developing a program where there are multiple little program inside. The main window show all the mini program, for the moment there is only one working but they will all be somewhat similar, so i click on the 'TimeEntry' button wich brings me to another view controller that way:

```
(IBAction)btnTe_clicked:(id)sender 
{

TELogin *ViewTELogin = [[TELogin alloc] init];


ViewTELogin.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;


[self presentModalViewController:ViewTELogin animated:YES];

[ViewTELogin release];

}
```

and then enter some data, validate and go to the next view controller, if i want to go back i use:

```
- (IBAction)btnMenu_clicked:(id)sender

{

[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

so far so good, the mini app works, but the code is ugly, in each view controller I have to set a Scroll View, some constant and UITextField method like that to prevent a text field to be hidden by the keyboard:

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

CGRect viewFrame =self.view.frame;
viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance; //animated distance is a CGFloat
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];
[self.view setFrame:viewFrame];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

And I'm pretty sure it's possible to make one Base class which implements the scroll view and textfield delegate and then for each view controller i would just have to import the base class and design my interface. But everything i tried so far was just a waste of time that's why i'm calling for help.

Comment: so u mean to say that all your views will have a scrollview and a textfield?

Comment: the scrollview only to center the text field when the keyboard appear and the number of text field per view varies

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with the [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html) documentation?

If not, try making your own View class and Model class. The model class would hold your data and maybe other properties (depending on your design) and the View class would hold the UITextField and any other views already inside the ViewController.

Comment: i already have a model class which act as a singleton because it stores all the fields of my sql 2008 query and make it accessible for all my view controller, but i think my problem is here, i have a view controller for each view and i'm sure i can have  only one view controller for lets say each mini app in my app, i tried to make my own view class without any xib so i could modify its interface where ever I instantiate it but no success, and i didn't know how to actually link an interface to it and add textfield that would all act the same(use the same delegate to not be hidden by the keyboa